# Camera editing application with accelerometer. Possible?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, camera, accelerometer

I am creating an application which allows the user to draw on their photo after they have taken one. 


I want to know whether it is possible to make use of the accelerometer for the drawing part instead of our finger. 
That means i selected a certain part of the picture where I want to draw on, then I use my whole phone as a "pen" to draw on the image instead of using my finger (using accelerometer).


May I know whether this is do-able? If so how?
Thanks a million!


Regards,
Grace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for very short quick lines.  Any stroke or pen location would have to be the double integral of acceleration, which amplifies system noise and miscalibration so quickly that anything longer would be completely inaccurate, like right off the page.

Answer (score 0):

Once you catch the accelerometer data, you can use the delegate methods with the code you want. But think about human interface.

Comment: I didn’t tried it, but it seems to be completely inaccurate as @hotpaw2 say in her/his answer. Anyway it’s possible to do, but you must do a really hard work for making it accurate and comfortable